# expo storeReview- how to delete a review

Tags: expo

1. SDK Version: 48.0.18
2. Platforms: Android
3. lib version: expo-store-review 6.2.1

I have an app that's still in the development phase (it has not been published yet), I'm using storereview (expo-store-review), but after I made the first review, the API no longer allows me to do another one.

I understand that I need to delete said review before making the next one, but I haven't found a way to do it.

I've checked my google play and my expo account to no avail.